# how can I reduce movement effects in a realtime sequence of video using OpenCV for Android?

Tags: android, opencv

I am new programming in OpenCV on Android. I have looked for my problem last days but I am not sure about its solution.
I am making a software that resizes frames of a sequence of video in realtime using OpenCV for Android (I am using java). I have observed that the image "dances". The objects are well, but they move between frames consecutives. This movement I think it is caused by my pulse because when the camera is static it does not ocurr.
The question is "how can I do to reduce this movement?
I read about Kalman filter, but I did not understand how this filter works, and how I have to implement it for my case. Is this the best way to reduce the movement effects?

Thanks to who can help me!

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your answer.
That class is only for C++ API and it is not in OpenCV for Android (last versión is 2.4.9.0).

Is there any algorithm that I can apply to video stabilization? An example to implement it in Java would help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Android development or the openCV java implementation but I know that OpenCV has a Video [Stabilization class](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/videostab/doc/videostab.html) that I have used with some pretty good results.

You can find a demonstration of the results on this [webpage](http://nghiaho.com/?p=2093)

It should do exactly what you want, if you can get it to work in Android.

You could also do it with goodFeaturesToTrack and Optical Flow:

If you detect the features on one image and store them in the following way:

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> featuresOld;
cv::goodFeaturesToTrack(oldFrame, featuresOld, 100, 0.01, 0.1);
```

You can use the following function to "fix" the next frame:

```
Mat stabilizeImage(cv::Mat newFrame, cv::Mat oldFrame, std::vector<cv::Point2f> featuresOld) {
    cv::Mat greyNew, greyBack;
    cv::cvtColor(newFrame, greyNew, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::cvtColor(oldFrame, greyOld, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> currentFeatures;
    std::vector<float> err;
    std::vector<uchar> status;
    cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(greyOld, greyNew, featuresOld, currentFeatures, status, err);
    cv::Mat correctionMatrix = estimateRigidTransform(currentFeatures, backgroundFeatures, 0);
    cv::Mat corrected;
    cv::warpAffine(newFrame, corrected, correctionMatrix, newFrame.size());
    return corrected;   
}
```

You can combine this into one function, but I had this code lying around to stabilze according to the first image of a movie.

Comment: HiThat class is only for C++ API and it is not in OpenCV for Android (last versión is 2.4.9.0).